# How can I copy directory itself with attributes?

Tags: shell-script, cp

I would like to copy only attributes of a directory to existing directory.

for example...

```
# mkdir /var/tmp/target-dir

# ls -ald /var/mail
drwxrwsr-x 2 root mail 4096  4月 27  2018 /var/mail
```

my image is as follows.. I found the --attributes-only option with cp command, but it is not my expectation.

```
# cp --attributes-only /var/mail /var/tmp/target-dir
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory '/var/mail'
```

I would like to copy only the attributes, and do not want to copy the contents of the /var/mail directory.

Are there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: chmod --reference=/var/mail /var/tmp/target-dir

Comment: backup your directory and try with `cp -r ----attributes-only`

Comment: Thank you for you comments. I could resolve with following three commands.

1. `chmod --reference=/var/mail /var/tmp/target-dir`
2. `chown --reference=/var/mail /var/tmp/target-dir`
3. `touch --reference=/var/mail /var/tmp/target-dir`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could resolve with following three commands.

- ### chmod --reference=/var/mail /var/tmp/target-dir
- ### chown --reference=/var/mail /var/tmp/target-dir
- ### touch --reference=/var/mail /var/tmp/target-dir

Here is reference of the attribution I would like to copy.

```
# ls -ald /var/mail
drwxrwsr-x 2 root mail 4096  4月 27  2018 /var/mail
```

This is the target directory. (permission, owner, timestamps are different)

```
 # ls -ald /var/tmp/target-dir
 drwxrwxr-x 2 user1 user1 4096  7月 16 07:09 /var/tmp/target-dir
```

*1. Copy the permissions with chmod command*

```
 # sudo chmod --reference=/var/mail /var/tmp/target-dir
 # ls -ald /var/tmp/target-dir
 drwxrwsr-x 2 user1 user1 4096  7月 16 07:09 /var/tmp/target-dir
```

*2. Copy the owner with chown command*

```
 # sudo chown --reference=/var/mail /var/tmp/target-dir
 # ls -ald /var/tmp/target-dir
 drwxrwsr-x 2 root mail 4096  7月 16 07:09 /var/tmp/target-dir
```

*3. Copy the timestamp with touch command*

```
 # sudo touch --reference=/var/mail /var/tmp/target-dir
 # ls -ald /var/tmp/target-dir
 drwxrwsr-x 2 root mail 4096  4月 27  2018 /var/tmp/target-dir
```

Finally, the /var/tmp/target-dir is the same attributes with /var/tmp/mail.

Comment: The comments helped me very much. Thank you for your support.